# scala: get all possible matches of a regular expression

Tags: regex, scala

I need to find all the pairs of word joined with the "and" word.

So far I tried with the following:

```
val salute = """.*?(\w+\W+)and(\W+\w+).*""".r

val salute(a,b) = "hello ladies and gentlemen, mesdames and messieurs, how are you?"
a: String = "ladies "
b: String = " gentlemen"
```

Now I'd like something like this:

```
salute.findAllMatches("hello ladies and gentlemen, mesdames and messieurs, how are you?")
List[(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)] = List((ladies,gentlemen), (mesdames,mesieurs))
```

I tried with

```
salute.findAllIn("hello ladies and gentlemen, mesdames and messieurs, how are you?").toList
res14: List[String] = List(hello ladies and gentlemen, mesdames and messieurs, how are you?)
```

But, as you can see, without success...

Comment: ...it's `Mesdames et Messieurs`, by the way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex

```
.*?(\w+\W+)and(\W+\w+).*
```

will already match everything because of .* before and after. Change it to (or similar based on requirements):

```
(\w+\W+)and(\W+\w+)
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting the result as a list of tuples as you described above you could do these two things:

Change your regex to be not so greedy i.e. to not consume the whole string at once
For example:

```
""".(\w+) and (\w+)""".r
```

Use *findAllIn* and use the RegexExtractor on all matches to get the parts in the catching parantheses

Putting everything together a solution producing the desired result might look like this:

```
val salute = """.(\w+) and (\w+)""".r
val string = "hello ladies and gentlemen, mesdames and messieurs, how are you?"

val results = for {
  salute(left,right) <- (salute findAllIn string)
} yield (left,right)

println(results toList)
```

results in

```
List((ladies,gentlemen), (mesdames,messieurs))
```